# Can not run robotframework-ride properly

Tags: python, robotframework

I have installed robotframework-ride on two PCs of mine. Everything works fine on one PC but could not have RIDE running on other PC.

I have the following installed on both PCs
 - Python 2.7.8 on win32
 - Robot framework 2.8.6
 - wxPython 2.8.12.1
 - robotframeowkr-ride-1.4.1b

When I tried to execute "python ride.py" on the second PC, I got a message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide__init__.py", line 74, in main
run(inpath, not noupdatecheck, debug_console)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide__init_.py", line 100, in run
ride = RIDE(inpath, updatecheck)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line
41, in __init_
wx.App.init(self, redirect=False)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_core.py", line 7981
, in init
self.BootstrapApp()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_core.py", line 7555
, in _BootstrapApp
return _core.PyApp__BootstrapApp(args, *kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line
49, in OnInit
self.namespace = Namespace(self.settings)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\namespace\namespace.py", line 41,
in init
self._set_pythonpath()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\namespace\namespace.py", line 62,
in _set_pythonpath
self._settings.get('installed robot version', None))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\namespace\robotlibraryloader.py",
line 35, in find_installed_robot_libraries
rf_file, rf_version = output.strip().split(', ')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
Use --help to get usage information.
```

Something more interesting is, if I uninstall robot framework from the second PC, I could execute "python ride.py" but of course there is no point doing this.

Anyone can help me out here?

Comment: Please provide a exactest error message you just can.

Comment: "too many values to unpack" is the exact message I got. there is nothing else.

Comment: no script line number, no variables etc?

Comment: Please create an issue in our tracker, I can provide help in debugging this mystery. https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues

Comment: There is nothing else, but this lonely message, "too many values to unpack". I suspect it has something to do with the order in which those modules get installed. As with the exact configuration, it works on one PC but not working on other.

Comment: Just created a ticket on Github. Thanks @janne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With kind assistance from janne, I have solved this problem. The cause is for the first PC I installed the correct "robotframework", but for the second PC I managed to install a wrong module, "robot" instead of "robotframework". That was why RIDE was not working.

I am sorry for making such a silly mistake. A big thank you to janne for his help.

should use: pip install robotframework 
should NOT use: pip install robot